# Unable to implicitly pass lambda as Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to write a helper class that, given an object of type `INotifyPropertyChanged`, can help you verify that a given property change did indeed fire the `PropertyChanged` event. This is a pattern we regularly follow, so I made the following class to aid in writing unit tests:

```
public class PropertyChangeHelper<TClass, TProperty> where TClass : class, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields
    private readonly TClass _model;
    private readonly string _propertyName;
    private readonly Action<TProperty> _setter;
    #endregion Fields
            
    #region Properties
    public bool ChangeEventFired { get; private set; }
    #endregion Properties
    
    #region Construction
    public PropertyChangeHelper(TClass model, Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>> property)
    {
        _model = model ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(model));
        
        if (!(property.Body is PropertyExpression propertyExpression))
            throw new ArgumentException("The given expression must be for a property, i.e., with { get; set; }.", nameof(property));

        _propertyName = propertyExpression.PropertyInfo.Name;
        _setter = targetValue => propertyExpression.PropertyInfo.SetValue(_model, targetValue);
    }

    ~PropertyChangeHelper() => _model.PropertyChanged -= RecordPropertyChange;
    #endregion Construction
            
    #region Methods
    /// <summary>
    /// Updates the property's value to the given target value.
    /// </summary>
    public void UpdateProperty(TProperty targetValue) => _setter.Invoke(targetValue);

    private void RecordPropertyChange(object _, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PropertyName == _propertyName)
            ChangeEventFired = true;
    }
    #endregion Methods
}
```

The idea is to be able to pass in an object (usually a VM) and a lambda expression to specify the property in question and then tell it to update the value and check that the event fired (or didn't, if the value was the same). The unit test may look something like this:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var vm = new VM();
    var helper = new PropertyChangeHelper<VM, int>(vm, x => x.SomeIntProperty);
    
    helper.UpdateProperty(5);
    
    Assert.IsTrue(helper.ChangeEventFired);
}
```

The problem I'm running into however, is that I'm getting an error for the `Expression` parameter, stating "Argument type 'lambda expression' is not assignable to parameter type `FastExpressionCompiler.LightExpression.Expression<System.Func<VM, int>>`.

I've seen the exact same thing done in other libraries, such as Moq, so I'm at a loss as to why this isn't working. Can anyone shed any light on what the compiler doesn't like about this?

Comment: Getting error in which line of the provided code?

Comment: The fifth line of the second snippet:

`var helper = new PropertyChangeHelper<VM, int>(vm, x => x.SomeIntProperty);`

Comment: Check if you have "using static FastExpressionCompiler.LightExpression.Expression" in your file and if yes - remove it.

Comment: I agree, you'll need to be using `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>>` instead. You can always convert it to `FastExpression` _within_ the constructor if you need to

Comment: I didn't have a static using, but did have a using for that namespace, but it's required for the `PropertyExpression` check.

Comment: Fully qualify the type of the parameter in the constructor then. The compiler doesn't chain the conversion from your lambda to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TClass, TProperty>>` to other types straight away, it needs to go into an intermediary variable (or parameter) first.

Comment: Can't imagine why it can be required, but anyway the core issue is your function has argument of one type (that fast compile lib Expression), while what you are passing is normal System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, so that doesn't work.

Comment: I see that my understanding of expressions is incorrect though. The `System.Linq` expression is not convertible to the `PropertyExpression`. That at least answers the question of why I couldn't pass the lambda in.

Comment: It's just called MemberExpression there (can reference both property and field though).

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library but quick look shows its for fast compiling of expressions, and you don't compile any here, so why use it in the first place?

Comment: Honestly, it didn't even occur to me that the FastCompiler version was anything other than what was automatically created for the lambda. Once it was pointed out that that was in fact `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`, it made much more sense why things weren't working. I don't have any reason to use the fast compiler version. I'll switch to using `MemberExpression` instead. Thanks for the help!